# Не работает функция в nodejs async

Tags: javascript, node.js, асинхронность

При получении данных сервер зависает, иногда при получении других данных выдает только результат с первой функции и зависает на второй

```
 async.each(body, 
        function (address, callback){
          repository = address.slice(address.lastIndexOf('/')+1, address.length);

          cmd.get('git clone '+ address, 
            function(data){

              child_process.exec('git log --pretty=format:"%ae [%an]"',
              {cwd: repository},
              function(err, stdout, stderr){  
              console.log(stdout);  //выводимый результат на этом останавливается выполнение        
                child_process.exec('rd '+repository+' /s /q', function(err, stdout, stderr){});


              }
            )})
          },
            function(err){
            // All tasks are done now

          }                         

        );
```

Comment: Что такое `cmd` (5-я строка)?

Comment: это один из модулей,работает с командной строкой

Comment: А вы уверены, что у вас все именно зависает? У вас же нет нигде обработчиков ошибок. Сдается мне, вы просто в какой-то момент получаете ошибку, игнорируете ее и **не вызываете** функцию обратного вызова одного из верхних уровней, чтобы вернуть результат. Как следствие, вам стоит убедиться, что у вас ни на одном из уровней объект `err` не содержит ошибки